# Setting ACL for new Parse user in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, acl

Im currently running into a problem with users having access to objects of another user in my app.

I know how to set the ACL when a user creates an object when they are already logged into the app, but I don't know how to set the ACL for someone signing up. When i set a navigation title to display the ["BusinessName"] column of a user, I receive business names from another created users column....thanks for your help!! greatly appreciated!

```
 @IBAction func signupFinalButton(sender: AnyObject) {

  var newUser = PFUser()
  newUser.username = username
  newUser.password = password
  newUser.email = email
  newUser["FirstName"] = firstName
  newUser["LastName"] = lastName
  newUser["BusinessName"] = businessName
  newUser["City"] = city
  newUser["State"] = state

  // This isn't seeming to work...
  newUser.ACL = PFACL(user: PFUser.currentUser()!) 
  or this 
  newUser.ACL = PFACL(user: PFUser())

  newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in
```

or maybe I am querying parse wrong? Im new to it.

```
     func navTitle () {
     var user = PFUser.currentUser()
     var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
     query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

     if error == nil {
     if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
     for object in objects {

     self.homeScreen.title = object["BusinessName"] as! String?
      }
     }else {

     self.homeScreen.title = "Home"
     }
```

Comment: Subclassing the user and objects for parse makes life much easier as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the ACL **after** the signUp has completed.

So in the delegate method,

```
func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser)

// set the ACL for the newly created user

newUser.ACL = PFACL(user: PFUser.currentUser()!)

//Then you can save the user, ie saveEventaully
```

If you are not using the PFSignUpViewController - just set the ACL in the code block of signUpInBackgroundWithBlock, then call the save once its been set.

This is the same when you want to create a role, the user needs to already exisit.

This is how to create a role within the same method body

```
let role = PFRole(name: user.objectId!, acl: roleACL)
role.users.addObject(user)
```

When first learning parse, i suggest creating new users via [this method](https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views).

Comment: awesome, thanks for the answer! I think i must be querying it wrong then....by looking at that query...maybe i need to be looking for objectIDs instead of querying the whole column? I though the query would be able to see what object belonged to the current user but its not registering it still..... I'm not to familiar with auto populating objectIDS for each user with different objects....any advice on getting objects more efficiently for data in my _User Class?

Comment: See link in answer. Also, object IDs are created automatically. Never edit those. Let parse take care of that. If a ACL is set on the PFUser class, then other PFUsers will not be able read / write that user, hence the need for the ACL. If you want to fetch all users, i.e. a Master User that can fetch all, create a Role. That role will be the Masters Object ID. So when you now create a new user, you associate that user with the Role. Thus when you as the master user can fetch all users. Check out this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBnVWWqFZX0 for parse basics. Hope I helped somewhat.

Comment: Hey bud Im at the point in my app where i am trying to create PFRoles. I am trying to have the user upon sign up be an administrator for the app and then from within the app can add multiple users with different priviledges. I am having issues with Parse registering that the user i created upon sign up is an Administrator.Hoping you could help! This is under the signupinbackgroundwith block method                                        var roleACL = PFACL()
let role = PFRole(name: "Administrator", acl: roleACL)  role.users.addObject(PFUser.currentUser()!)                role.saveInBackground()

Comment: When i sign up in the app with a new user,         user.ACL = PFACL(user: PFUser.currentUser()!)
        user.saveEventually { (results, error) -> Void in
            
            if error == nil {
                let roleACL = PFACL()
                let role = PFRole(name: user.objectId!, acl: roleACL)
                role.users.addObject(user)
                role.saveEventually(nil)                
            }
        } If i want create a new user from within app - I use cloudCode.I pass in the new users username, email etc and create a new user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply DogCoffee, where in that code that you replied with can i assign the new user to the "Administrator" Role. I thought "let role = PFRole(name:"Administrator", acl:roleACL) is where i did that, but your code looks a little different than what I posted. I want the user upon sign up to be automatically granted the administrator privilege. Parse Sees the new Role created, but doesn't add the user to the Role. thanks again!

Comment: I also use the objectID as the role names. This way I can have many users playing the role as the Admin.

Comment: ok...Any advice on a some good tutorials on where to get started with cloud code? Im pretty new to swift and parse. I am still stuck on not being able to assign the new user to the Role....                                                  var role = PFRole.roleWithName(roleName, acl:roleACL)
for user in usersToAddToRole {
  role.users.addObject(user)
} hopefully ill be able to get it working soon!

Comment: Not really - i started here https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code spend many many hours getting it to work. Slow going as you need to upload the code via terminal and compile. Parse now has a new Query test which may speed things up for you. Check out this for good overall coverage on parse and ACL / Roles - https://www.udemy.com/swift-ios-chat-app-from-scratch-community-course/

Answer (score 3):

What @DogCoffee says is right, but there's an even simpler way to handle it.

In your app delegate inside your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function, you can set a default that will always use the appropriate ACL. You don't have to manually set the ACL for signing up new users, logging in existing users, saving objects, etc. It's all automatic.

Here's what my Parse stuff in my app delegate looks like and works great:

```
ParseCrashReporting.enable()
Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

Parse.setApplicationId("<YOUR APP ID>", clientKey: "<YOUR CLIENT KEY>")

//Always set the ACL value to the current user
PFACL.setDefaultACL(PFACL(), withAccessForCurrentUser: true)
```

I hope that helps. Good luck!